# ngx-datatables element of arrays

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I have arrays of elements within a structure:

```
rsDoorInfo
{
  tDoorNumArray:["701","702",...,"800"],
  tStartDate:["17-JUN-2018 15:51:00",","17-JUN-2018 15:51:00",...,"17-JUN-2999 15:51:00"],
  tEndDate:["17-JUN-2019 15:51:00", "17-JUN-2019 15:51:00",...,"17-JUN-2019 15:51:00"]
}
```

There are a 100 elements within each array. I am having trouble displaying this data on an ngx-datatable. I would like to be displayed as:

```
Door Number | Start Date | End Date
```

Is there any way of doing this without changing the data structure? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a template inside the datatable-column so you can extract any info form the row object.

Use the `tDoorNumArray` as your aray in the table rows. Inside each row, you can get the index and so access the data by the index

```
<ngx-datatable [rows]="rsDoorInfo.tDoorNumArray">
  <ngx-datatable-column name="Door Number">
    <ng-template let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
      {{ row }}
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>

  <ngx-datatable-column name="Start Date">
    <ng-template let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
      {{ rsDoorInfo.tStartDate[rowIndex] }}
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

It let you use the current structure but I recommend you to map this data so your view does not have to find all data for each table row.